# Is there a C671x DSP development kit with more than 16M Flash?

Tags: dsp, dev-kit

TI's standard kit C6713DSK has only 256K bytes of Flash, which is too small for my application. Is there a third-party DSP kit that has a larger Flash like 16M bytes?

Comment: What on earth do you need all that for? Can you offload it into an external eeprom?

Comment: How much larger, and what is your application, needing such an amount of flash? I almost think you are looking for an FPGA

Comment: Switching to an FPGA would not solve your code storage problem, if anything it would make it much worse.  Like pjc50 said, you'll need an external EEPROM.  And asking whether any devkits have a large EEPROM onboard is a very reasonable question, but it borders on being a shopping recommendation, so it might get voted off this site.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen The application needs lots of initialized data. I don't quite understand how FPGA could solve the problem.

Comment: DSP, number crushing, fpga. That was on the top of my head, but i would go for external flash. Sorry for the bad comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Daughter Card interface of the DSK6713 is memory mapped though the same interface the on-board Flash and SDRAM is:

[image: memory map]

You could buy a prototyping daughter card from [Link Research](http://www.link-research.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=3_13&products_id=31) and add however much memory you need for storage through that interface.

[image: prototyping board]

Comment: It looks a nice option. But I am not sure whether there is a large capacity Flash chip with the same HTSSOP package as the onboard Flash. All the large capacity Flash chips I've found so far are of BGA packages...

Comment: @JasonGeng Why do you need it to be in the same package as the onboard? And I found 53 ICs in the 16M-32M range for Flash memory in various pinned SOP packages on Digikey.

Comment: Glad to know it doesn't need to be in the same package. Though there's another interface board already stacked on top of my DSK. Anyway, this may be the closest answer for this question.

Comment: @JasonGeng It's a bit more money, but this version is stackable: http://www.link-research.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=3_13&products_id=34 So you can stack your other daughter card on top of it. Just be sure to use connections that won't interfere with the operation of your other card.